Ambiguity for boundary conditions after conformal transformation
Abbreviations

EOM = Equations of motion
BCs = Boundary conditions
CT  = conformal transformation

Intro
I was playing around a bit with EOMs, action principle, CTs and BCs. There, I met a problem. Namely, I seem to arrive at different BCs for my EOM depending on whether I perform a CT at the level of the action integral or at the level of the EOMs.
Preliminaries
In order to specify my problem, consider some Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$ (four dimensions) of the form
$$\mathcal{L} \equiv \mathcal{L}(\phi, g)$$
Now I perform a CT, and to be more precise, I compactify my spacetime.
$$g = \lambda^2 \tilde{g} \quad , \qquad \phi = \lambda^{-1} \tilde{\phi} \quad , \qquad \text{and at boundary:} \quad \lambda^{-2} = 0 \quad $$
with $\lambda \equiv \lambda(x)$. For simplicity, we will favourably assume that the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ transforms as
$$\mathcal{L}( \phi, g) = \mathcal{L}( \lambda^{-1} \tilde{\phi}, \lambda^2 \tilde{g}) = \lambda^{-4} \ \mathcal{L}(\tilde{\phi}, \tilde{g})$$
in other words: the action integral is form-invariant under this CT.
$$I(\phi, g) = \int \! dV \ \mathcal{L}(\phi, g) = \int \! (\lambda^4  \ d\tilde{V}) \ \lambda^{-4} \ \mathcal{L}(\tilde{\phi}, \tilde{g}) = \int \! d\tilde{V} \ \mathcal{L}(\tilde{\phi}, \tilde{g})$$
and the (usual) EOM is
$$\nabla_i \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial( \nabla_i \tilde{\phi})} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \tilde{\phi}} = 0$$
Let's say on the boundary (no additional condition, but rather just the limit of the equation) the EOM reduces to $\tilde{\phi} = 0$ because all other terms go to zero. The EOM therefore naturally offers this as a boundary condition, that I must adhere to. I cannot chose e.g. $\tilde{\phi} = 1$, because then the EOM and the BC would be discontinuous.
However
If I perform the same conformal transformation not on the Lagrangian and the action integral, but rather on the EOM itself, I get
$$\lambda^{-3} \bigg( \nabla_i \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial( \nabla_i \tilde{\phi})} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \tilde{\phi}} \bigg) = 0$$
This is all nice and dandy. But on the boundary, I have $\lambda^{-1} = 0$, so that my boundary condition must no longer read $\tilde{\phi} = 0$ but rather $\tfrac{1}{\lambda^3} \tilde{\phi} = 0$. Since $\lambda^{-1} = 0$, I am no longer required to have $\tilde{\phi} = 0$. I could choose e.g. $\tilde{\phi} = 1$, and the equation would still be satisfied.
Question
As both EOMs were obtained by the same CT, I expect them to be somewhat equivalent. However there are these discrepancies, where I do not understand how they came to pass. Which BCs are the "correct ones"?

Example
As an example, consider a black hole in asymptotically AdS spacetime. The metric in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates reads
$$g = - f(r) \, dv^2 + 2 \, dv \, dr + r^2 \, d\Omega^2 \quad , \qquad f(r) = 1 - \frac{2m}{r} + r^2$$
In order to compactify, I choose a new coordinate $z = 1/r$ so that
$$g = - f(z) \, dv^2 - \frac{2}{z^2} \, dv \, dz + \frac{1}{z^2} \, d \Omega^2$$
and the conformal factor shall be $\lambda(z) = \tfrac{1}{z}$, so that the metric $\tilde{g} = \lambda^{-2} g$ is perfectly fine at the conformal boundary $z = 0$. I am moreover considering the Klein-Gordon field
$$\mathcal{L} = g^{\mu \nu} \, \nabla_{\mu} \phi \, \nabla_{\nu} \phi + m^2 \phi^2$$
which is conformally invariant for $m^2 = -2$. My equations of motion, respectively are
$$2 \tilde{\phi}_{,vz} - \Big[ \partial_z( z^2 f(z) ) \Big] \tilde{\phi}_{z} - \Big[ z^2 f(z) \Big] \tilde{\phi}_{,zz} - \Big[ z f'(z) - \tfrac{m^2}{z^2} \Big] \tilde{\phi} = 0 \tag{1}$$
and
$$z^3 \bigg( 2 \tilde{\phi}_{,vz} - \Big[ \partial_z( z^2 f(z) ) \Big] \tilde{\phi}_{z} - \Big[ z^2 f(z) \Big] \tilde{\phi}_{,zz} - \Big[ z f'(z) - \tfrac{m^2}{z^2} \Big] \tilde{\phi} \bigg) = 0 \tag{2}$$
In the limit $z \rightarrow 0$ and with $m^2 = -2$, equation $(1)$ yields the BC
$$2 \tilde{\phi}_{,vz} - \tilde{\phi}_{,zz} = 0$$
whereas equation $(2)$ yields no BC at all, as the equation vanishes due to the prefactor of $z^3$. In relevant literature, the case $m^2 = -2$ is described as giving rise to a freedom in the choice of boundary conditions (see e.g. here equation (1.3) therein). They often choose the Robin BCs
$$\big( - \tilde{\phi}_{,v} + \tilde{\phi}_z - \kappa \tilde{\phi} \big)(z=0) = 0$$
[1] Quasinormal mode spectrum of the AdS
black hole with the Robin boundary condition; Kinoshita et al. (2024)

Update/Attempt
I could of course NOT transform the volume element within the action integral, such that the action has the form
$$I(\tilde{\phi}, \tilde{g}) = \int \! dV \ \lambda^{-4} \mathcal{L}(\tilde{\phi}, \tilde{g})$$
Then I obtain a prefactor of $\lambda^{-4}$ in my equations of motion. But it seems wrong to transform every quantity EXCEPT for the volume element MERELY to obtain the desired result.

I think I understand where your confusion is coming from. The issue revolves around how boundary conditions (BCs) arise when performing a conformal transformation (CT) either at the level of the action integral or directly on the equations of motion (EOM).

When you perform the CT at the level of the action:

You transform the Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$, the fields, the metric, and the volume element consistently.

The action remains form-invariant under the CT, as you've shown:
$$
  I(\phi, g) = \int dV \, \mathcal{L}(\phi, g) = \int d\tilde{V} \, \mathcal{L}(\tilde{\phi}, \tilde{g})
  $$

When you vary the action to derive the EOM, you get boundary terms from integration by parts:
$$
  \delta I = \int_{\mathcal{M}} \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} - \nabla_i \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\nabla_i \phi)} \right) \delta \phi \, dV + \int_{\partial \mathcal{M}} n_i \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\nabla_i \phi)} \delta \phi \, dS
  $$

To ensure the action is stationary (i.e., $\delta I = 0$) for all permissible variations $\delta \phi$, the boundary term must vanish. This typically leads to specific BCs, like $\tilde{\phi} = 0$ at the boundary.


When you perform the CT directly on the EOM:

You apply the transformation directly to the EOM without considering how the action's variation generates boundary terms.
The transformed EOM might include a prefactor that vanishes at the boundary (since $\lambda^{-1} = 0$ there), which can misleadingly suggest that no specific BC is required, or that different BCs are acceptable.


So, why the discrepancy?
The crux of the issue is the boundary terms that arise when varying the action. When you perform the CT at the action level and then vary the action, you properly account for these boundary terms, which dictate the necessary BCs to make the action stationary. Ignoring these terms when transforming the EOM directly can lead to incomplete or incorrect BCs.
In your specific example with the Klein-Gordon field and $m^2 = -2$:

You're working at the Breitenlohner-Freedman bound in AdS space, which allows for multiple acceptable fall-off behaviors of the scalar field near the boundary.

The field $\tilde{\phi}$ behaves near $z = 0$ as:
$$
  \tilde{\phi}(z) \sim A z + B z^2
  $$

Both terms are normalizable, giving you the freedom to choose different BCs, such as Dirichlet, Neumann, or Robin conditions.

This is why, in some literature, you see Robin BCs like:
$$
  \left( -\tilde{\phi}_{,v} + \tilde{\phi}_z - \kappa \tilde{\phi} \right)\big|_{z=0} = 0
  $$


Conclusion:
To determine the correct BCs, it's important to consider the variation of the action and the associated boundary terms. These boundary terms are essential for ensuring that the action principle is well-defined and that the EOM follows from a stationary action without leftover boundary contributions.

I appreciate your answer. Yet, I still don't see how the Robin condition is consistent with the BC arising from the action. 1.) How does one conclude the behaviour near $z=0$ as $\tilde{\phi} \sim Az + Bz^2$? 2.) The BC arising from variation is:
$$\int_{\partial M} dS , n(\phi) , \delta \phi = \int_{\partial M} d\tilde{S} , \delta \tilde{\phi} ( \lambda n(\tilde{\phi}) - \tilde{\phi} n(\lambda) )$$
yielding
$$\sim 4\pi \int dv , \delta \tilde{\phi}  \big( \tilde{\phi}_v + \tilde{\phi}z + \sqrt{1+ z^{-2}} \tilde{\phi} \big) ; \bigg|{z=0}$$
How does Robin solve this?

Note here, that I realised my example with asymptotical AdS spacetime does not have a form-invariant action under CT, as there is an additional divergence-like term in the Lagrangian. I did not realise this before. So if I am not mistaken, the boundary integral should transform as in the previous comment.
